# Surprising result in probability : not linear result

Tags: probability

Given a city of $10 000$ cars, $1/5$ of the cars are black. We admit that $1/500$ of the cars are going to have an accident.

We find that the probability that 15 cars have an accident is : $5$%

And that the probability that $3$ black cars have an accident is : $19$%

I'm surprise of such result. How is it possible ? Logically, shouldn't we have the same result, because we have $5$ time less cars and we ask for $5$ time less accident ?

I was thinking that if we have $P(X = k) = p$ and then we look at a sample of half the size of the first study, we are going to get $p/2$. But if we ask for $P(X = k/2)$, we should again find $p$...
Isn't $P(X = k) = P(Y = k/2)$ where $Y$ is the same random variable as $X$ but for a sample half smaller ?

I'm feeling my question isn't clear. I don't know how to correctly express it... I'm not used to english language of probability...

Comment: What does $\frac 1{500}$ mean here?   Do you mean $.2\%$?  But then what are you saying about the $15$ cars?

Comment: i'm sorry Lulu don't understand the remark

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What exactly are your assumptions?

Comment: There is a city, a number of cars fixed, a pourcent of black cars and a probability for cars to get involved in a accident. $ \ $  I computed the probability for certain cars to get involved in an accident and the result shocks me ; is it clearer?

Comment: I don't understand.  You told us that there are $2000$ black cars, so what does it mean to say that the probability that there are $3$ black cars is $19\%$?

Comment: oh I see the problem, i'll edit that. Just a small problem of understanding ; I thought it was clear that way. Is it now ok?

Comment: Ok, so you are saying "each of $10,000$ cars has a $\frac 1{500}$ chance of having an accident.  Given that $2000$ of these cars are black, what is the probability that exactly $3$ have an accident", is that right?

Comment: yes it is. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Ok, but that';s a simple binomial computation.  It comes out to about $.1955$.  Where is the confusion?

Comment: I wasn't expecting to be that misunderstood ^^' I'll edit the question precisely.

Comment: Both of the computations you describe are simple binomial expressions.  What is it about them that you find puzzling?

Comment: The 15 cars are not all black, are they?  So why are you comparing this situation to where the 3 cars are all black?

Comment: Just consider the normal approximations.  With a sample of $10,000$ we have a mean of $20$ and a standard deviation of about $4.47$.  Thus seeing $15$ accidents would be less likely than a $1 \sigma $ event.  With a sample of $2,000$ we have a mean of $4$ and a standard deviation of about $2$.  Thus seeing $3$ accidents would be about a $.5 \sigma $ event.   So the latter should be much more probable, as it is.

Comment: So what you're saying is that taking less cases in consideration makes the risk bigger ? So each car will be more at risk of getting in an accident because the graph of repartition will be flatter than the one for a big sample ? I'm not sure to understand. Let me first read your answer, thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not saying anything even remotely like that.  This is a question about variance...each car has the same probability of being in an accident, but if you have a smaller sample the variance of observed results will be greater.

Comment: I've posted something below, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general phenomenon!  The variance of observed results in a small sample is much higher than in a large sample.

Let's see how that plays out here.

The exact calculations are routine, and it seems you have done them already.  So I'll try and explain why they should be intuitive.

To do so, consider the normal approximation to the distributions.

First, for the $10,000$ cars.  Here of course the mean is $\frac {10,000}{500}=20$ and we compute the standard deviation as $$\sigma_{10,000}=\sqrt {10000\times \frac 1{500}\times \frac {499}{500}}\;\approx \;4.47$$

Thus, observing exactly $15$ accidents is a $1.12\sigma$ event

Now, for the $2,000$ black cars.  Here of course the mean is $\frac {2,000}{500}=4$ and we compute the standard deviation as $$\sigma_{2,000}=\sqrt {2000\times \frac 1{500}\times \frac {499}{500}}\;\approx\; 2$$

Thus, observing exactly $3$ black cars in accidents  is a $.5\sigma$ event.

It follows that the latter should be much more probable than the former, as it is.

Comment: +1 I'd put the last sentence first.

Comment: @EthanBolker  Not a bad idea,  I'll do that.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense. I'm sorry for this really easy and basic question. I'm still learning the basics of probability :) It makes now sense. For anyone wanting something visual to understand, take a look at that : https://shiny.rit.albany.edu/stat/binomial/